# JSON character size limit using curlPerform or getURL

Tags: r, rcurl

I am running into what appears to be character size limit in a JSON string when trying retrieve data from either `curlPerform()` or `getURL()`.  Here is non-reproducible code [1], but it should shed some light on the problem.

```
# Note that .base.url is the basic url for the API, q is a query, user 
#  is specified, etc. 
session = getCurlHandle()
curl.opts <- list(userpwd = paste(user, ":", key, sep = ""), 
                  httpheader = "Content-Type: application/json")
request <- paste(.base.url, q, sep = "")
txt <- getURL(url = request, curl = session, .opts = curl.opts, 
              write = basicTextGatherer())
```

or

```
r = dynCurlReader()
curlPerform(url = request, writefunction = r$update, curl = session, 
            .opts = curl.opts)
```

My guess is that the `update` or `value` functions in the `basicTextGather` or `dynCurlReader` text handler objects are having trouble with the large strings.  In this example, `r$value()` will return a truncated string that is approximately 2 MB.  The code given above will work fine for queries < 2 MB.

Note that I can easily do the following from the command line (or using `system()` in R), but writing to disc seems like a waste if I am doing the subsequent analysis in R.

```
curl -v --header "Content-Type: application/json" --user username:register:passwd https://base.url.for.api/getdata/select+*+from+sometable > stream.json
```

where `stream.json` is a roughly 14MB json string. I can read the string into R using either

```
con <- file(paste(.project.path, "data/stream.json", sep = ""), "r")
string <- readLines(con)
```

or directly to list as

```
tmp <- fromJSON(file = paste(.project.path, "data/stream.json", sep = ""))
```

Any thoughts are very much appreciated.

Ryan

[1] - Sorry for not providing reproducible code, but I'm dealing with a govt firewall.

Comment: How are you accessing R?  GUI, terminal, .. ?

Comment: I've tried using the R GUI on OS X as well as the terminal.  Same results.